# How to read CPU temperature on a shared server?

Tags: acpi, temperature

I would like to read my CPU temperature with PHP, but I cannot find the relevant info. All paths under `/proc/acpi/thermal_zone` appear empty. I have tried:

- /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THM0/temperature
- /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THRM/temperature
- /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THR1/temperature

None of these (appear to) exist. What is the correct path to the CPU temperature monitor?

`phpinfo()` says:

```
PHP Version 5.4.12
Linux infong 2.4 #1 SMP Thu Feb 14 13:02:49 CET 2013 i686 GNU/Linux
Safe mode is off
Apache
```

Comment: Seconding zorlem, the temperature sensor is not a useful way to seed a PRNG. Get your entropy from `/dev/urandom`, that's what it's for.

Comment: @Gilles Since we are here in unix.SE and PHP questions are posed and answered in Stackoverflow, I was (obviously, I thought) aiming at receiving an answer explaining how to read my CPU temperature. The part about seeding a PRNG is irrelevant here, and I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

The thermal zones temperatures for each core are available from `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone?/temp` on kernel versions > 3.x.

Your desire to seed `mt_rand()` using your CPU temperature makes no sense. According to the [mt_rand() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php), seeding the PRNG is done automatically in PHP versions 4.2.0+. Even if you want to seed it manually using [mt_srand()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php), doing so using your CPU temperature is an extremely bad idea. Most of the CPUs maintain a pretty constant temperature of operation (eg. 46⁰C) and the recent intel "i" processors (i3, i5, i7), the cores are simply switched off when not needed - so the temperature is 0. You're much better leaving it to default (not specifying a seed value), than trying to seed the PRNG with a constant value.

Also, if you need the `mt_rand()` for generating any crypto values make sure to read the warinings in the documentation - it does not produce cryptographically secure random numbers.

Comment: /sys is empty on my system. Thank you for the thoughts on seeding mt_rand. I'll think about that.

Comment: The phpinfo() output in your question looks incomplete. What version is the kernel on the server?